# Is it possible to break ng serve build if there are linting issues?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like the ng serve stops if there are linting issues. Is it possible to configure Angular cli on this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah! It was actually pretty easy! Add npm lint script before npm start: It will exit before starting the server if there are linting issues!:)

Indeed, you need to use npm command to start the app instead of ng serve.

Update the `package.json` to look like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lint && ng serve",
    "lint" : "tslint" // your lint conf here..
 }
```

Comment: My juniors always use ng serve :-(, is there anyway that we can implement this with ng serve?